# How can I convert a spatial dataset (raster and vector) to COCO format for object detection?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gis, geospatial, detectron

I am doing an object detection project using detectron2, which requires datasets to be in COCO format. This format needs images as png and polygons in a JSON file. However, spatial images (e.g. satellites or drones) are georeferenced (`tif` format), and the annotations/labels also have geographical coordinates (`shp`/`geojson` format). Getting a regular image from a `tif` file is pretty straightforward using `rasterio` and `numpy`, but getting the annotations in the correct coordinate system has been difficult because they need to point to the position of the polygons in the `png`, not the georeferenced image.

As an example, say I have a 300*300 px satellite image bounded by these coordinates: 75W 10N, 70W 5N. The coordinates of the polygons will be within the region of the geographical box. Once I transform the geo-image to a normal image, it will lose its geographical reference, so the coordinates of the polygons should be in (0, 300), (0, 300).

Is there a way to translate the polygons from geographical coordinates to positional coordinates in an image so that I can make a dataset in COCO format?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_find_the_coordinates_of_every_pixel_in_a_satellite_image_knowing_the_coordinates_of_some_pixels) answer your question?

Comment: Have you checked this [repo](https://github.com/Dingyuan-Chen/shp2coco)?